# Datatool cannot use math macros in tabular headers from csv file

Tags: tables, math-mode, datatool

I am making a LaTeX table using a CSV file and the `datatools` package.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
,$x$,$p_x$,
$x$,$0$,$i \hbar$
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{mytable}{data.csv}
\DTLdisplaydb{mytable}

\end{document}
```

This will compile cleanly. However, if I change the first row (which will become the header) to include a macro (e.g. `,$x$,$\hbar$,`) I get a whole bunch of errors on the `\DTLloaddb{mytable}{data.csv}` line.

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\mathchar
l.12 \DTLloaddb{mytable}{data.csv}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
....(and so forth)...
```

Things I have tried that did not work:

1. Quoting ("\hbar")
2. Ensuremath (\ensuremath{\hbar})
3. Using tabs as delimiters instead of commas.
4. Unrolling the csv file into equivalent `datatool` commands.

These are the equivalent commands:

```
\DTLnewdb{mydata}
\DTLnewrow{mydata}%
\DTLnewdbentry{mydata}{}{$x$}%
\DTLnewdbentry{mydata}{$x$}{$0$}%
\DTLnewdbentry{mydata}{$p_x$}{$i \hbar$}%
\DTLdisplaydb{mydata}
```

They give the same errors as the csv file.

Manually specifying the headers, however, works fine:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
$x$,$0$,$i \hbar$
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,headers={,$x$,$\hbar$}]{mytable}{data.csv}

\DTLdisplaydb{mytable}

\end{document}
```

I would like to avoid manually specifying the headers, however, if possible.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The culprit is `\hbar`, which is very fragile. Unfortunately even `\protect` does not help. `:-(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using something unexpandable as an identifying label. The same problem would arise if you tried doing something like `\label{\hbar}`. If the headers contain commands or special characters you need to explicitly set the keys to simple labels. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
$x$,$0$,$i \hbar$
,$x$,$p_x$
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb[keys={column1,column2,column3}]{mytable}{data.csv}
\DTLdisplaydb{mytable}

\end{document}
```

(You'll probably want something more descriptive than `column1` etc.)

Comment: Thanks! I don't suppose there's any way to automatically adjust the number of keys to match the number of columns in the csv file, is there?

Comment: @bariumbitmap At the moment there isn't an automatic way of doing this, but I might see if I can add an option to do that.